# Acceptance testing using Mocha + Zombie.js when page content is dynamically loaded with JavaScript

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, mocha.js, zombie.js

I am having a problem that I have been looking for solutions for a while.
I have a page (Express app) which has a div#content. Initially, it has nothing in it. On page load, a JavaScript function is called to determine if the user has already logged in. If not, it populates a login form inside div#content. Otherwise, the user profile will be shown in the same div.

This app is a one page app. All the actions are handled by Ajax. Most of the content is generated dynamically as well.

Now, I am trying to write some acceptance tests for this app with Mocha and Zombie.js. However, even a simple test like this one won't pass:

```
assert.equal(this.browser.text('div#content h1'), 'Login');
```

.. because div#content is empty.

I am just wondering if there is way to get the page with all dynamically populated content. I tried browser.html(), set debug to true, set runScripts to true, use browser.wait() for div#content, and many other ways but just can't get it to work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I am just new user to zombie and javascript. and exactly same problem facing now. thanks for posting. i will share the answer if i find solution in net or in my experiment. thanks.